# SQL Select where value = 'X' or min value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a large customer database where the customer table has people and their relationship to an organisation.  People may belong to multiple organisations (*this allows divisions within organisations*). People with multiple organisations must have a default organisation, this is usually determined where `isDefault = T`, however the front end application can also figure the default application where `isDefault = F` by selecting the `MIN(RowID)`.

So in the table below we know `PersonId` `3` has a default `OrgID` of `11` (IsDefault = T)
However, I need to figure out the query for finding PersonID 12's default.
ie

```
Select orgId as default from myTable
where personID = 12
and isDefault = 'T'
```

If 0 rows returned then perform a query like this:

```
Select orgId as default from myTable
where personID = 12
and 
RowId in (select Min(rowId) 
from myTable 
where PersonId = 12)


RowID | PersonID  | OrgId  |  isDefault
1     |    12     |   14   |     F
2     |    12     |   17   |     F
3     |    3      |   11   |     T
4     |    3      |   14   |     F
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS? MySql, MS Sql, Oracle?

Comment: MS SQL 2008. It's a summary of the actual table, but should be enough for some-one smarter than me to figure out ;-)

Comment: @Xardax99 is it possible to have a row like this?  5  |  3  |  17 |  F ? i mean what will it return if `PersonID = 3` has 2 OrgID (*where IsDefault = F*)?

Comment: Hi johntotetwoo, do you mean like personID 12 where it has 2x different different OrgID and both are 'F'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get what you want by ordering twice, first by whether IsDefault is T or F, then by RowId, and take the top result:

```
SELECT TOP 1 OrgId as [Default]
FROM MyTable
WHERE PersonId = 12
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN IsDefault = 'T' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    RowId
```

Comment: Awesome work, short, sweet and works. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: @Xardax99 - Make sure to use this query for less number of records otherwise decision making(sorting) for individual record in the `Order clause` can create `Performance issue`.

Answer (score 1):

In MySql server you can do a union with limit 1:

```
SELECT OrgId AS `default`
FROM (
    SELECT OrgId FROM MyTable
    WHERE PersonID = 12
    and isDefault = 'T'

    UNION

    SELECT OrgId FROM MyTable
    WHERE PersonId = 12
    AND RowId in (
        SELECT MIN(RowId)
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE PersonId = 12
    )
) SomeName LIMIT 1;
```

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 OrgId AS [default]
FROM (
    SELECT OrgId FROM MyTable
    WHERE PersonID = 12
    and isDefault = 'T'

    UNION

    SELECT OrgId FROM MyTable
    WHERE PersonId = 12
    AND RowId in (
        SELECT MIN(RowId)
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE PersonId = 12
    )
) SomeName;
```

Comment: Thanks rcdmk, works well, I've given Bort the answer as his query was shorter, but yours worked as well, so again thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Didn't tried executing this but expecting this should work. IsDefault will short circuit the subquery.

```
  Select orgId as default from myTable o
   where personID = 12 
       and  
       ( IsDefault = 'T' OR
                   RowId = (select Min(rowId)  
                               from myTable i
                             where i.PersonId = o.PersonId
                           )  
        )
```

Comment: Thanks Shantanu, when I tested this against a person that did have a 'isDefault' and multiple orgIDs it returned all of the orgIds. Thanks for helping though

Answer (score 0):

Putting this logic into one query is rather complicated.  You have to union all the results together, keeping track of where the result come from.  Then you have to count how many rows come from the first part, and keep only the rows from the appropriate result set.

```
select orgid, mytable
from (select t.*, sum(which) over (partition by null) as whichcnt
      from ((Select 1 as which, orgId as default
             from myTable
             where personID = 12 and
                   isDefault = 'T'
            )
            union all
           (Select 0 as which, orgId as default
            from myTable
            where personID = 12 and 
                  RowId in (select Min(rowId) from myTable where PersonId = 12)
           )
          ) t
     ) t
where whichcnt > 0 and which = 1 or whichcnt = 0
```

If you can use TSQL instead of of a single query, then you can just run the first version, check the number of rows in the results, and then decide which result set to take.

Comment: wow, one day I hope to understand this query ;-) Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select PersonID ,OrgID from mytable where isDefault='T'
union all

select personID,min(OrgID) [default]
from myTable P
where  not exists 
(select * from mytable C where P.PersonID=C.PersonID and C.isDefault='T')
group by personID
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, this ones not returning the personIDs with multiple OrgIds and isDefault = 'T'. Cheers for helping though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how big the table is what are the indexes.If say rowid has unique clustered index 
and personid and isdefault has a nc index I will use two statemnts.

```
 declare @orgid int = null
 select @orgid =orgid from table where personid = 12 and isdefault = 'T'
 if (orgid  is null)
 begin
 select @orgid = orgid 
 from mytable
 where rowid = (
 select min(rowid)from table where personid = 12 and isdefault = 'F'
 )
 end
```